# Unable to configure cancancan in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

I am using `active_admin` and `cancancan` gem.

## ability.rb

```
    if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    elsif user.regular?
        can :read, :all
    else 
        can :read, :all 
    end
```

I have `role` column in database. It is basically a blog.

## schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_18_221247) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.date "published_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "category_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "role"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

### user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  def admin?
    role == "admin"
  end
  def regular?
    role == "regular"
  end
  def guest?
    role == "guest"
  end
end
```

### Goal

My goal is to not allow a guest user to create a new Post.

### Problem

The problem I am getting access denied for both admin and guest user though I have clearly defined what different types of user can do in **ability.rb**.

#### If you need more info about the code you can check it on [github](https://github.com/Pushpamk/stackoverflow/tree/master/Test).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the `user` that's passed to the Ability class. Remove this line:

```
user = User.new(role: "guest")
```

Comment: I have removed that line but still same funtion as before. You may wanna look at user.rb that I just added.